# Adding Grids within Grids

Tags: umbraco7, umbraco-mvc

I've just come across the new **Grid** layout system in Umbraco, which seems quite interesting, however I can't seem to find a way to include a grid within a grid.

I've added a simple 2 column row onto a page in the example below, but now I want to add another 2 column row within it to fill in the 2 red squares. Is this not possible or am I missing something obvious?

If I click any of the layouts at the bottom it instead adds them as an extra row to the bottom of the page rather than inside an existing grid.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The only way to include a grid in a grid (that I'm aware of) is to use the Doc Type Grid Editor package: https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/doc-type-grid-editor

This package allows any Document Type to be the basis for a grid editor.  I was able to create a grid editor that was a set of tabs where each tab had a grid data type for the content.  The data type was specific to tabs so you couldn't create tabs in a tab.

I also created a package (v7 Dialog Expander) to allow the dialog flyout to expand: https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/v7-dialog-expander.  I did this because a grid in the small width of the dialog flyout was just too small.

It is definitely possible and actually has worked out well so far.  That said, I would tread lightly here because there could be issues that we haven't yet discovered as this solution is still on a development project.

Comment: Hello BeaverProj! how did the above solution go (i.e. the grid within a grid, with DTGE in between as the facilitator)? Did you discover any issues? Have you tried using Courier with that solution?

Comment: Overall, it went well.  It did require a more experienced content editor.  We did not use Courier on that site, so I'm not sure if that worked properly.